# Error running a Sveltekit app on cpanel using phusion passenger

Tags: node.js, passenger

I have deploy my app to the dir but i after i open the url i got this error below. Please help a brother.

app.js

```
import { handler } from './build/handler.js';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

// add a route that lives separately from the SvelteKit app
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    res.end('ok');
});

// let SvelteKit handle everything else, including serving prerendered pages and static assets
app.use(handler);

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('listening on port 3000');
});
```

[image]